# Omniauth 2.0 + Google "hd:" tag not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authorization, omniauth

Despite adding the "hd: " tag to my /config/initializers/omniauth.rb file, users not in the domain can still login.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :google_oauth2, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base, Rails.application.secrets.secret_token, 
    skip_jwt: true, 
    scope: 'profile, email',
    image_aspect_ratio: 'square', 
    image_size: 48, 
    access_type: 'online', 
    hd: 'domain.com',
    name: 'google'
end
```

When logging in with an account that has the domain @gmail.com, the user is still able to login.

Incase this is of use:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
class << self
    def from_omniauth(auth_hash)
        user = find_or_create_by(uid: auth_hash['uid'], provider: auth_hash['provider'])
        user.name = auth_hash['info']['name']
        user.location = auth_hash['info']['location']
        user.image_url = auth_hash['info']['image']
        user.url = auth_hash['info']['urls']['user.provide.capitalize']
        user.email = auth_hash['info']['email']
        user.save!
        user
    end
end
end
```

Suggestions to solve this issue or alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The `hd` tag only sets the request URL parameters when connecting to Google's oAuth system. It can easily be changed by a user, and even when not changed I've found that it's inefficient at block unwanted domains.

The best way around this is to enforce a validation on your `User` model like so:

```
validates :email, format: { with: /\b[A-Z0-9._%a-z\-]+@domain\.com\z/,
          message: "must be a domain.com account" }
```